# Created a nodejs/express app that works on localhost put gives a bad gateway when it's on the real server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

So I am building a nodejs app using express, all went well and the server runs perfectly on my pc (localhsot) but when i upload it to a server it gives a bad gateway error. This is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var breadcrumbs = require('express-breadcrumbs');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var sqlite = require('sqlite3');
var fs = require('fs');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var handlebars  = require('./helpers/handlebars.js')(exphbs);
app.engine('hbs', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/group67',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// Breadcrumbs middleware
app.use(breadcrumbs.init());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), {flags: 'a'});
app.use(logger('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

// Set Breadcrumbs home information
app.use(breadcrumbs.setHome());

// Mount the breadcrumbs at `/admin`
app.use('/', breadcrumbs.setHome({
  name: 'Webshop',
  url: '/'
}));

app.use('/group67', index);
app.use('/group67/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


module.exports = app;
```

My www file in the bin looks like this (this is automatically created by the express install)

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8063');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}


function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

I am a beginner so I hope someone can help me figure things out.

Comment: Where are you hosting it? AWS, heroku, digital ocean...

Comment: On a server of my university

Comment: Does the port your app is listening to allows traffic?

Comment: Yes we tested it with a simple program that just sends "hello world"

Comment: @Steven Is it the app throwing that error or some reverse proxy server like nginx ?

Comment: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu) this is printed under the error, is that what you mean?